# How to get last part from the URL with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

`enter code here`    I have following URLs (part of). Among them I need to get the details 
    after final "/"

```
/magasins/vos-magasins/le-bhv-marais
/magasins/vos-magasins/le-bhv-marais-homme
/magasins/vos-magasins/bhv-marais-parly2
/magasins/le-bhv-marais-la-niche
/magasins/vos-magasins/mobicity-au-bhv-marais
/magasins/vos-magasins/gucci-au-bhv-marais
```

I know how to match all the part as follows

```
/magasins/[a-z-]+/?[a-z0-9-]+
```

But I need to get last part after the final "/".

Comment: Try "slash and any word" `/\/[\w-]+$/`?

Comment: Do you have to use a regular expression? This could be done much easier without using one.

Comment: `var arr = url.split('/'); console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);`

Comment: @Quentin, the previous answers aren't give the correct solutions for me. May be the question title is same but not the content!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will work for you:

```
(?<=\/)[a-z0-9-]+?$
```

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6e2dEG/2)

Explanation:

> `(?<= )` lookbehind finds a pattern to start your match (but will not include this inside your matching group).
>
> `\/` matches a literal `/`
>
> `[a-z0-9-]` matches a character that's alphanumeric, or hyphen `-`
>
> `+?` that character must occur one or more times until next pattern
>
> `$` end of input

Since not all browsers support *lookbehind*, I've also provided this version for javascript:

```js
var regex = /\/([a-z0-9-]+)$/

match = "/magasins/vos-magasins/le-bhv-marais".match(regex); 
console.log(match[1]); // le-bhv-marais

match = "/magasins/vos-magasins/le-bhv-marais-homme".match(regex);
console.log(match[1]); // le-bhv-marais-homme

match = "/magasins/vos-magasins/bhv-marais-parly2".match(regex);
console.log(match[1]); // bhv-marais-parly2

match = "/magasins/le-bhv-marais-la-niche".match(regex);
console.log(match[1]); // le-bhv-marais-la-niche

match = "/magasins/vos-magasins/mobicity-au-bhv-marais".match(regex);
console.log(match[1]); // mobicity-au-bhv-marais

match = "/magasins/vos-magasins/gucci-au-bhv-marais".match(regex);
console.log(match[1]); // gucci-au-bhv-marais
```

Comment: here "?" means optional of +

Comment: when added to `+`, `+?` means one or more times but *lazy* match, meaning it will repeat as few times as possible while remaining true. Without `?`, the `+` alone is *greedy*, meaning it will repeat as many times as possible. In this example it probably doesn't make a difference and you can safely omit the `?`.

Comment: I've also updated answer to work with most browsers (not requiring lookbehind)

Comment: @user You're most welcome!